# Nginx service not starting on Windows 10 - nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile()

Tags: nginx, windows-10, file-permissions

I have an Nginx service that's configured to start automatically on my Windows 10; however, this morning, the service wouldn't start. 
The error log says: nginx: `[alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "C:\someForlderName\build\distribution\.\nginx/logs/error.log" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified)`

Looking at the path in the error log above, I do NOT have the /logs/ folder on my local system so it looks like Nginx doesn't have the proper permissions to create that folder?

I'm setup as an ***admin user*** and my service is set to ***Log On As - Local System Account***

> This only happens on Windows 10; but the service starts and works on
>   older Windows  i.e 8.1

So does anyone know how to grant administrator's permissions to Nginx so that Nginx can create folders and files on Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 10):

You need:

To install nginx/Windows, download the latest mainline version distribution (1.13.8), since the mainline branch of nginx contains all known fixes. Then unpack the distribution, go to the nginx-1.13.8 directory, and run nginx. Here is an example for the drive C: root directory: (**Run cmd as administrator**)

```
cd c:\
unzip nginx-1.13.8.zip
cd nginx-1.13.8
start nginx
```

Go to: http://localhost:80 -> test install

Goback to console cmd: "nginx -s stop"

Run for next time:

1. Config with file: "C:\nginx-1.13.8\conf\nginx.conf"
2. Open cmd as administrator
3. Run bash: "cd C:\nginx-1.13.8"
4. Run nginx with bash: "start nginx" . If you run with bash: "nginx", will get trouble for exit nginx.
5. And

   nginx -s stop   #fast shutdown

   nginx -s quit   #graceful shutdown

   nginx -s reload #changing configuration, starting new worker processes with a new configuration, graceful shutdown of old worker processes

   nginx -s reopen #re-opening log files

Comment: For me I did everything correctly but for two hours I couldn't do 'start nginx' at the command-line. That command itself quickly started the server for me.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Just how to set it up. More explanations needed

Answer (score 4):

Under the directory that you run nginx.exe, try to create a directory named logs, and a file named error.log under log.
It should pass this error.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm running nginx on windows service

Comment: Hi @eagles, can you paste the error message? I am not sure what specific error it is for "doesn't work". You can also try to specify the error_log with a absolute path in the configure file. For more information, you can see: [nginx error_log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with starting the nginx server, but after looking at it closely and trying to run the command in different consoles, I realized it just a simple issue of a missing path.

How I solved it was to cd into the containing folder for the nginx.exe file (which actually contains error logs and all the necessary files) and then run the `nginx` command which started the server and fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. After downloading zip file, you have unzip.
2. Make sure that you dont have nested folder names. You have to copy your folder which has `nginx.exe` file in it, and paste it into `C:/` folder.
3. While running commands, like `nginx -s stop`, make sure that current your working directory is same as the `nginx.exe` file.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnt2P.png)

Comment: The part the `nginx -s stop` should run in the same folder of nginx.exe helped me a lot!! Apparently Nginx for windows is ages behind Apache for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx  start on default port 80, not 8080. Try localhost:80 on browser.

If you want to change port, open  C:\nginx-1.16.1\conf\nginx.conf with text editor. 
change port number  what you want use default port.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
to:

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
```